# Как проверить, что строка состоит только из пустых или невидимых символов?

Tags: php

Как проверить, что строка состоит только из пустых или невидимых символов? То есть разрешены любые символы, но строка не может быть, например, такой: "       ".

Comment: *но строка не может быть, например, такой: " "* А как по мне, так она как раз и состоит "только из пустых или невидимых символов". Хотя я затрудняюсь сказать, что такое "пустой" символ. А невидимость символа - она как бы зависит от используемого шрифта (если мы говорим о выводе на экран или печать) и "доброты" средства вывода, которая вместо таких символов запросто может вывести, к примеру, знаки вопроса...

Comment: Есть специальная и замечательная функция `trim`, рекомендую почитать.

Comment: @And `trim` удаляет весьма ограниченный набор символов.

Comment: @Akina,я думаю его должно хватить, для задачи автора, к тому-же, можно использовать `character_mask`.

Comment: @And Читал, читал... а Вы всю тему читали, включая ответы и комментарии? неразрывный пробел ака CHAR(160) она удалит, как полагаете?

Comment: @Akina, смотрите второй аргумент функции, там можно задать любой диапазон от и до или перечислить N - количество символов для удаления..

Comment: Вот в такой форме, с полными пояснениями - это уже похоже на ответ, достойный публикации...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться функцией:
[trim](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php) - Удаляет пробелы (или другие символы) из начала и конца строки.

Если второй параметр не передан, `trim()` удаляет следующие символы:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), обычный пробел.  
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), символ табуляции.  
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), символ перевода строки.  
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), символ возврата каретки.  
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), NUL-байт.  
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), вертикальная табуляция.
```

Можно указать конструкцию `..` для обозначения диапазона символов.

```
// удаляем управляющие ASCII-символы с начала и конца $binary
// (от 0 до 31 включительно)
$binary = "\x09Example string\x0A";
$clean = trim($binary, "\x00..\x1F");
```

[Источник](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php)

Следующие условия не вернут `Все ок!`:

```
$string = "      ";

if(trim($string)) {
    echo"Все ок!";
}

$string = "\x09\t\r\n\x0A";

if(trim($string,"\x00..\x1F")) {
    echo"Все ок!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Уточните в своём вопросе, что подразумевается под пустыми и невидимыми символами. Здесь мы проверяем, что в строке встречается хотя бы 1 любой непробельный символ, а если будут одни пробелы, то функция вернёт '0'.

```php
if (preg_match_all('/[\S]+/', $string)) {
    //..
}
```

Comment: Не подходит, тогда, скажем, строка "Oh shit, here we go again" не пройдёт. То есть мне нужно фильтровать строки, где чисто те символы, о которых вы сказали. То есть пробелы, табуляция и пр., то есть строки, где нет букв, цифр, знаков доллара, точек и пр. пр.

Comment: @IWProgrammer А как насчёт em-space, non-breaking space и прочей ерунды подобного толка? А их по большому счёту - ну очень дохрена...

Comment: @IWProgrammer, отредактировал свой ответ, в соответствии с вашим комментарием.

Comment: @Akina, по всей видимости такие символы придётся перечислять через токен `[^\x{YYYY}-\x{YYYY}]`, где YYYY — номер символа в таблице unicode.

Comment: Угу... но ведь помрёшь перечислять - и всё одно чёта пропустится. Или всплывёт - но завтра.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=""; $string1=" "; 
if($string=="" or $string1==" "){ echo "пустая строка";}else{echo "Всё в порядке"; }
```

Comment: Не пойдёт. Ваш код выдаст "Всё в порядке" на строку, где, скажем ,2 пробела, а не один, или есть другой невидимый символ (перево каретки, например, или табуляция)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Oh shit, here we go again";
$string_clean = str_replace([" ", "\n"],"", $string); // убираем все пробелы, и прочее что не нужно ([" ", "\n"])
if(strlen($string_clean) == 0 ){ //если после очистки строки ее длина больше 0 символов значит в строке есть текст
    echo "пустая строка";
}else{
    echo "Всё в порядке <br>";
    echo $string;
}
```